# Can we simulate hydrogen atom formation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, simulations, atoms

Is it possible to simulate the formation of a hydrogen atom from a single free electron and a free proton?

The Hamiltonian for the Schrodinger equation of a free electron and free proton is the same as a bound electron and a bound proton. How can we tell apart these two situations?

I know the total energy of the bound electron and proton is negative, however, how does this work in a simulation in which initially the electron and proton are free and at a distance? Should we then take into account some emission process during which the energy of the electron and proton becomes negative?

Considering the radiation to take into account the final negative energy of the bound state of electron and proton, rises another issue. The electron and proton are not necessarily destined to form a hydrogen atom and it could be that they still stay free as another possible outcome. Then is it the initial conditions plus the radiation process that determine the final fate of the system as a bound state or free state?

All in all, is there a simulation of this process available?

Comment: The final state is a superposition of such states as: 1) excited hydrogen atom (in lots of possible configurations) plus a bunch of photons (different bunches for different configurations), 2) ground state atom plus another bunch of photons, 3) free electron and proton (in lots of possible configurations) plus a bunch of photons (again, different bunches for different configurations). The simulation is gonna be hard. But, maybe someone has done it already...